# Correct way of wrapping app component when using redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-toolkit

As someone newbie in using redux toolkit, I ponder the correct way of wrapping the `<App/>` component in the `index.js` file. My current structure looks like this;

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <App />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I wonder if it is okay to wrap the `<App />` with the `<Router>` component (BrowserRouter from react-router-dom) or should I take the `<Router` into the `<Home />` page? and if I don't could this be a problem in the future development of the project?

Comment: Usually, the `Router` is placed at the top of the tree. If you need fine grained control over where the `Routes` can be defined, then you can move the Router down the component tree.

Comment: In what cases I would need "grained control"?

Comment: It is very rare that you would need this but 1 case I can think of is say a stackoverflow post. You have 1 sidebar on the left and 1 sidebar on the right. This stays constant for all posts. Imagine all the pages had these 2 sidebars and the routing only changes the middle content, then it would make sense to move these 2 sidebars out of the `Router` so that developers don't accidentally also add these sidebars under a route. Like I said, it is pretty rare and almost all medium to large-scale projects have `Router` at the top (because it gives flexibility).

Comment: You can also look at static site generators like NextJS (which also has the capability of doing SSR) so that you don't have to manage the Routing manually.

Comment: Thank you for such a good explanation. I guess I pretty much got it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter at all where exactly you place those.

- The `<Router>` has to be higher than any `<Route>` you use.
- The `<Provider>` has to be higher than any component using `useDispatch` or `useSelector`.

But apart from that rules, it's down to preference and there is no "technical best way".